# Dynamic filepath in data flow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to achievie thing which is possible in Copy Activity - create a dynamic filepath like raw/division/yyyymm/yyyymmddhhhhss but due to my linked service I am forced to using Dataflow. Is it possible to achieve such things? I see no dynamic variables on inline dataset in "Sink" section of dataflow. Any help would be greately appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can use dataflow parameters in the inline dataset file path.

Create a string type parameter in the dataflow.

[image]

In the sink, give your inline dataset and in the sink settings, give your container. As you want to store the output in a single file, use **Output to single file** in the **File name option** and give the parameter that we created earlier in the **Filename**.

[image]

Now, in the pipeline, we need to give the pipeline expression to the dataflow parameter in dataflow activity.

```
@concat('/raw/division/',formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyy'),'/',formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyyMMdd'),'/',formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyyMMddHHmmss'),'.parquet')
```

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you, my dataset is SAPTable so I don't have that much of a options as SQL Server for instance but I figured it out by "SetVariable" activity using @concat and  formatDateTime(utcNow()) functions